# Who loses the fight in Shang-Chi, and where do they go afterwards?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, shang-chi-legend-of-the-ten-rings

In *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings*, our protagonist visits a fight club in Macau, where he sees

> Wong

fight and defeat a big, kinda hulking monster-type thing. I thought this being looked a bit like

> the Abomination, from *The Incredible Hulk*.

Was it? And, for bonus points, where did

> Wong take the creature to after the fight, when he opened the sling ring portal?

Comment: yes - IMDB, wiki all confirm the original actor and the character (and have for months fwiw) Heck, probably even the credits...

Comment: “and have for months fwiw” — sure, I just prefer to see the movie when I see the movie, rather than have various fragments of it described to me during the months before it’s released.

Comment: I stand corrected in that Roth goes uncredited in the film itself (but still easily searchable after watching the movie), as do a couple of other folks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I thought this being looked a bit like the Abomination, from The *Incredible Hulk*. Was it?

**Yes.** The creature is confirmed to be Abomination (Emil Blonsky) in *She-Hulk: Attorney at Law* S01E02 "Superhuman Law". In the same episode, Blonsky retains Jennifer Walters (She-Hulk) as his attorney for his parole hearing.

Wong addressed Blonsky by his first name in *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings*. ("*That hurt, Emil!*")

> where did Wong take the creature to after the fight, when he opened the sling ring portal?

As revealed in *She-Hulk: Attorney at Law* S01E03 "The People v. Emil Blonsky", Wong forcibly took Blonsky from his cell in the Department of Damage Control (DODC) supermax prison undetected (until a video of the fight was leaked) as part of his Sorcerer Supreme training. After the fight, Wong returned Blonsky to his cell.

Screencap from *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings* showing Blonsky's prison cell through the portal:

[image: screencap described above]

Relevant dialogue:

> **Walters:** Do you wanna explain to me why you failed to mention that you not only escaped from prison, but you were also recorded doing so?
> [...]
> **Blonsky:** Nah, 'cause I was forced to leave my cell, but I returned of my own free will.
> **Walters:** Who forced you to escape this insanely high-security prison undetected?
> **Blonsky:** A Sorcerer Supreme of the Mystic Arts, and his name is...

> **Wong** (*to Walters*)**:** Everything Mr. Blonsky told you is factual. I extracted him from the prison against his own wishes, because I required a worthy opponent as part of my training to become Sorcerer Supreme. And as Sorcerer Supreme, I insist that he not be punished for my actions.

> **Wong** (*to the parole board, testifying as a witness*)**:** In regard to Mr. Blonsky vacating his cell, I gave him no choice. But it was absolutely his choice to return.
> I offered him asylum at the Kamar-Taj, which is truly lovely this time of the year. But he was quite adamant he be returned to serve out his sentence and repay his debt to society.

Comment: Just curious is there any sense on whether Wong is being truthful here?  Just going by Shang-Chi it seems like Wong has a fondness for gambling and fight clubs and may be using his position to cover for his vices.

Comment: @lucasbachmann Wong definitely needed a scary-looking opponent to lengthen the odds on him winning so he could clean up. It’s not like he’s got savings from his 9 years at Target.

Answer (score 9):

The producer of *Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings*, Jonathan Schwartz, confirmed that it was indeed the Abomination in that scene.

> There will be more of Abomination to come, so more of that story to be told. With regards to Shang-Chi , it sort of came down to who would be the coolest character for this moment? Who do we want to see in that ring? And then understanding who would make sense for whatever ongoing stories they have going on out there in the bigger universe.
>
> <sub><sup>[Shang-Chi Producer Confirms Tim Roth's Voice Performance as Hulk Villain Abomination (Exclusive)](https://thedirect.com/article/shang-chi-tim-roth-hulk-abomination-voice-exclusive)</sup></sub>

He also confirmed that Tim Roth -- the actor who previously played the Abomination in *The Incredible Hulk* (2008) -- provided some or all of the voicework for the character.

> Roth did some vocalization for us... he certainly was part of that process.
>
> <sub><sup>Shang-Chi Producer Confirms Tim Roth's Voice Performance as Hulk Villain Abomination (Exclusive)</sup></sub>

As for where that portal they went through led to, I don't think that's been confirmed anywhere, but Kevin Feige has revealed that he will appear in the upcoming *She-Hulk* series on Disney+.

> Kevin Feige confirmed at the Disney Investor's Meeting that She-Hulk on Disney+ will include appearances by Mark Ruffalo as Bruce Banner/the Hulk and Tim Roth as the Abomination.
>
> <sub><sup>[Marvel's Abomination Will Finally Return To MCU in She-Hulk Disney+ Series](https://thedirect.com/article/marvel-abomination-return-mcu-disney-plus-she-hulk)</sup></sub>